# How to set up vue-tsc to properly work with lint-staged (staged files)?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, tsc, vue-tsc

With a recent introduction of TypeScript to a project, our team decided not to do a full-blown type check inside a CI pipeline, but rather fix the problems gradually. One plan was to run a compiler on staged files only and check for any errors present. I tried multiple approaches inside `.lintstagedrc.js`, for example:

1. Running a `vue-tsc` command with a `--project` flag pointing to a custom `tsconfig` which contains `include` property which is an array of absolute paths to all the staged files
2. Running a `vue-tsc` command with flags specified in a way that mimics the tsconfig that's being used in the app

The problem with the first approach is (I believe) that if any other component/file is imported inside the component - TS will throw an error that the import or its type declaration can't be resolved because only staged files are inside `include` of the `tsconfig`.

The problem with the second approach (so far) is that there's no way I can provide path mappings (which are actively used throughout the app). I'm sure there would be some additional errors.

Here's the code snippet of a `.lintstagedrc.js`:

```
const fileSystem = require("fs");

function typeCheckStagedFiles(files) {
  const configName = "tsconfig.lintstaged.json";
  const config = JSON.parse(
    fileSystem.readFileSync("./tsconfig.app.json", "utf8")
  );
  config.compilerOptions.noEmit = true;
  config.compilerOptions.composite = false;
  config.include = files.map((file) => file.split("dashboard/")[1]);

  fileSystem.writeFileSync(`./${configName}`, JSON.stringify(config));

  return `vue-tsc -p ${configName}`;
}

module.exports = {
  "src/**/*.{ts,cts,mts,js,cjs,mjs,vue}": [
    "prettier --write",
    "eslint --fix --max-warnings 0"
  ],
  "src/**/*.{vue}": [typeCheckStagedFiles]
};
```

Here's the `tsconfig` that's being overridden:

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "checkJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@tests/*": ["tests/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["ES2021", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "env-override.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.